# Laravel belongs to adds double quotes to executable query

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, eloquent

Am using Laravel with MYSql and MongoDB connections. When using belongsto  Eloquent ORM relationship between MYSQL and MongoDB, it gives me the below error:

> "Call to a member function `prepare()` on `null`"

Mysql Model: **Audios.php**

```
class Audios extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'audios';

    public function getAudioPlaylist()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('AudioPlaylists:;class','id','audio_id');
    }
 }
```

Mongo model: **AudioPlaylist.php**

```
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as MongoModel;

class AudioPlaylist extends MongoModel
{
    protected $collection = 'audio_playlists';
    protected $connection = 'mongodb';

    public function playlistAudioTracks()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Audios::class, 'audio_id', 'id');
    } 
}
```

Mongo Collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c2f519368c5f214022c4102"),
    "playlist_id" : "5c2cace668c5f2382e5ef464", 
    "audio_id" : 1, 
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2019-01-04T12:29:07Z"), 
    "created_at" : ISODate("2019-01-04T12:29:07Z")
}
```

The audio table contains the related `id` 1. The `hasMany` relation on `Audio`s model works fine, whereas the inverse doesn't work.

When debugged by logging the queries in the log file, the query for the belongsTo was as below and when used the same in PhpMyAdmin it throwed syntax error:

> [2019-01-04 18:41:13] production.INFO: select audios.*,audios.id as is_favourite from "audios" where "audios"."id" in (?) and "is_active" = ?

Comment: Is `'AudioPlaylists:;class'`  a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally got the solution after a long day strugle. The solution was to add,

```
$connection  = 'mysql';
```

in the Audios.php model, since the relationship belongsTo from AudioPlaylists model tries to frame a query using MongoDB instance since the connection attribute was missing.